# Login fail with SourceTree when attempting to connect to my personal repository hosted on Raspbian

Tags: git, ssh, raspberry-pi, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a personal web server hosting many projects and I'm willing to set up a third-party Git repository.

### Setting up

I have installed Git on the remote server, created the directories needed and now, trying to connect to it via SourceTree.

I have generated a SSH key via PuttyGen, uploaded to `/var/git/.ssh/authorized_keys` for which I set up a `777` chmod.

I've actually followed this tutoriel : https://www.sheevaboite.fr/articles/installer-serveur-git-auto-heberge-partie-1 but set up a password for user `git` instead of not.

### Connection to `ssh://git@MY-IP:/project.git`

When I try to connect to my server from my local machine using SSH Client `OpenSSH` it says that `The OpenSSH agent is running but the server still rejected your connection. You may need to add the correct key to your agent by selecting Tools > Add SSH Key` which I did but the passphrase never matches so I cannot add my key.

When I try to connect to my server from my local machine using SSH Client `PuTTY / Plink` it says `Access denied Access Denied Access denied Access denied FATAL ERROR: Server sent disconnect message type 2 "Too many authentification failures for git"`. It was asking me for a password for user `git` at one time but does not anymore. Anyway, I could never make the password to match.

I'm not sure about the clearness of my explanation as I'm not expressing myself in my native language.

Any help would but gratefully appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem after upgrading to Windows 10.

I wasn't being asked for my ssh's key passphrase.

`start SourceTree.exe`

Starting SourceTree from the Command Line fixed the issue. It now asks for the passphrase.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately, this old environment is not live anymore. I therefore cannot test your answer if it's a valid one. As such, I won't accept it and rather wait for commenters to let me know if your solution works.